# Spark streaming and performing operations on streamed dictionaries

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Curiously I want as a check to see the number of k, v pairs in a series of dictionaries that I am streaming in, however I find that I do not seem to be able to do this.

```
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1", 5006) 
json_format = lines.flatMap(lambda recieved: json.loads(recieved))
dict_format = json_format.flatMap(lambda x : len(x) ).reduce(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

For example I get the following error:

```
File "/home/xx/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1776, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/home/xx/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 236, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I can assume that we have a series of dictionaries - there is not failure in the `json.loads()` but I cannot seem to take this simple length.

Answer (score 0):

Spark expects that the function provided to [`flatMap`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.DStream.flatMap) will return a traversable/iterable result (such as a list) for each element it processes from the source RDD/DStream. The `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` error probably occurs because Spark is attempting to iterate a non-iterable value returned from one of the lambdas you are passing to `flatMap`.

The second `flatMap` call (`json_format.flatMap`) is definitely a problem, since `len(...)` will always return an `int`, and so it is the most likely culprit here. Since it would appear that the intent is to perform a 1-to-1 transformation to an `int` (namely, the length), you should be able to fix that issue by replacing `flatMap` with [`map`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.DStream.map) instead.

Whether the *first* `flatMap` call is valid depends on the input. If you are certain that each line in the source file is a string which will parse to a JSON array, then it should work as anticipated. However, if JSON parsing of any line in the file will produce a type *other* than array, then the parsing function will send a non-iterable result to `flatMap`, and the job will fail with an error similar to the one you are seeing currently:

```
>>> type(json.loads('{"asdf": "qwerty"}'))
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(json.loads('[{"asdf": "qwerty"}, [1,2,3]]'))
<class 'list'>
>>> type(json.loads('3'))
<class 'int'>
```